# Is there a way to open SketchUp models on Android?

Tags: applications

I have a model designed in Google SketchUp, I want to be able to show it on my Android device (Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy Tab) - is there any way to do that?

I did try DAE View 3D from Afanche Technologies - but it is not working on the exported dae model and also registers for every intent.

Comment: Did you search in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/apps)? FYI: Questions that ask "Is there an app that does X?" are generally unwelcome here. ([FAQ]) This site, and Stack Exchange in general, do better with questions that are about an actual problem you face.

Comment: I did search play store and there is no app. My actual problem is displaying SketchUp model on android.

Answer (score 1):

You can try exporting from SketchUp to other formats such as DXF (tutorial to do this in the free version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kei0gmOwZ5Q)) for which there are [viewers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dxf%20viewer&c=apps) for Android.  More information [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sketchupruby/q1vU46AqxD8).

Comment: I don't see option to export into DXF on SketchUp free?

Comment: I linked the tutorial in the answer, I will edit it to be more obvious.

Comment: Answears should be self contained, not just link to video, which shows zou how to google the link to the plugin - sic. Improve and I will accept

Comment: Actuallz the output does not seem to be compatible with any free DXF android viewer. I don't know about paid ones